# Tshark not running via gdb to learn tcp and udp dissectors

Tags: centos, wireshark-dissector

I have successfully installed wireshark on centos 6.4 I can run the command tshark it works perfectly fine. I want to run gdb so that I want to learn how it decodes tcp and udp packet as I am writing an application where I need to dissect these two types of packets. When I run libtool --mode=execute gdb tshark it run and stop at here (gdb) it not capturing anything. The reason I want to run it via gdb is to learn how both tcp and udp have been dissect as I dont want to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it would be practical to learn tcp dissection through just gdb.

Why not directly examine the source code? It's available for download [here](http://www.wireshark.org/download/src/wireshark-1.10.1.tar.bz2). All dissector can be found under "epan/dissectors/".

You might specifically want to look at packet-tcp.c and packet-udp.c files, particularly the functions dissect_tcp() and dissect_udp() respectively. Also, a quick read through [this](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/ChDissectAdd.html) tutorial for creating dissectors might help you understand the coding conventions of this project quickly.

Comment: thank you but before you mention I already gone into the folder and grab both packet-tcp.c and packet-http.c. The problem now I can follow the flow accordingly. I have now managed to capture the whole payload of the ethernet packets. So from there I want to follow till I can get the url if it exist. So I got hold of the codes I dont know how to traverse.

Comment: The problem now is here I am stuck dissect_tcp(tvbuff_t *tvb, packet_info *pinfo, proto_tree *tree). I am not too sure about tvb, pinfo and tree ? What are these exactly ?

Comment: @After reading the tutorial just to confirm is it *tvb is the whole payload or just the whole packet?

Comment: @new14 "The "tvb" argument to a dissector points to a buffer containing the raw
data to be analyzed by the dissector; for example, for a protocol
running atop UDP, it contains the UDP payload (but not the UDP header,
or any protocol headers above it).  A tvbuffer is an opaque data
structure, the internal data structures are hidden and the data must be
accessed via the tvbuffer accessors." Check "doc/README.developer" for more info.

Comment: say from ethernet the payload will be ip then in the ip the payload will be either tcp or udp right? So how go to from here? in this case what will the tvb be the whole payload from the start or only from the particular layer?

Comment: @new14 "say from ethernet the payload will be ip then in the ip the payload will be either tcp or udp right?" Yes. "So how go to from here? in this case what will the tvb be the whole payload from the start or only from the particular layer?" I don't quite understand what you're asking here. But the tvb passed to tcp dissector points to a buffers with the entire tcp header, but I'm not 100% certain if it'll also contain headers of protocols running atop tcp since a tvb can be created without them. There are some nice comments about this under "epan/tvbuff.h" from line 67 you should read.

Comment: ok I will look further into those comments cause I am lost here with tvbuff.h. Do you think wireshark is too big and overkill for me?

Comment: @new14 What you're trying to do is a little big, which is why I thought using gdb was not going to work, since you need to consider IP fragmentation and other things. If you're finding difficulties with wireshark project, you can also raise your doubts in http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/ . The people there are extremely savvy and helpful.

Comment: the tvbuff.h do give me some better idea and its say that every level its broken down further. Is there any other similar simpler to learn dissector.

Comment: @new14 Which protocols are you familiar with? The dissectors for vlan, isis, ftp etc, look pretty small. But are you familiar with these? You might want to download some capture files for a protocol of your choice from the internet, open them in wireshark and compare the codes. Also, you should probably finish udp before tcp(but you're probably doing this already), since it is comparatively straightforward and there should be some similarities. Only part that may be slightly tricky should be reassembly of segments: http://wiki.wireshark.org/TCP_Reassembly

Comment: yes I am new into dissection I am studying the packet structure from wikipedia thus I was going through the commmons one like udp and tcp. I am going through first ethernet then ip then next is tcp/udp. I guess this the flow right?

Comment: @new14 The order you are following is the best choice.

Comment: thank you for the confirmation is there any simple dissection method or tool for beginners like me to pickup

Comment: @new14 I am unfamiliar with analyzers apart from wireshark, although there is a nice list of packet analyzers in Wiki. Apart from these there is also tcptrace, but I just started going through the code 5mins ago and can't tell where dissection is taking place. If you want to create a new tcp/udp dissector you could look at how dissection is being done in these projects. If all you want to do is understand the protocols, then Wirehark has an excellent GUI interface that you can use to understand the packet structures.

Comment: @Judging from this few dissector what is the best way to go out is it best to convert the hex value into human readable but I dont think it can cover all? OR to to go into the bit value ?

Comment: any input on this matter from your experience ?

Comment: @new14 Your question is not very clear to me. It is always nice if you can show the hex in human readable form. If you don't want to cover all of the header fields you can instead focus on more important fields like port num, ip addr, flags etc.

Comment: sorry for my question. What I mean is that like those details in the payload. How normally do the the dissection tools decide if any data exist or not? I guess they do hex to binary conversion ?

Comment: @new14 I don't see why you'll need to convert to binary since both hex and bin will represent the same value anyway. For dissection, you basically already know the expected structure of a protocol header, and your header will also contain information about the header length and the protocol in the payload. So, if your protocol header and payload is say 44 bytes, you'll read the next 44 bytes. Within this block, you already know the order and size of each protocol field, so define your own variables and load your values into them. Is this what you're asking?

Comment: actually I am using pf_ring to capture the packets. It can split the ethener header and the rest of the payload. Thus from the ether type I can know is say 0x0800 is IPV4,0x86DD is IPV6, 0x0806 is ARP etc. The rest of the payload when I view is now in hex format. But I dont get you how to discect information directly from the hex is that possible.

Comment: @new14 I finally understand what you're saying. Converting those hex values to binary and populating your structures sounds good.

Comment: I am not too sure whether that is the right way how all the dissector work because I guess just by using hex wont be helpful rite. So say after the first 44 bytes what is the best mechanism to further dissect it on ? So 44 will be for TCP's case and the rest will be different accordingly. So say if its TCP and I wanna look for the url what is the best method to look for it.

Comment: @Any comment on my dissection idea ?